# Disable checkbox highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

When I click a checkbox and then immediately after I start typing, it highlights the checkbox. When I press spacebar while it is highlighted, it checks it.
Is there a way to disable spacebar checking it or just disable the highlighting of it in some way?

Comment: That's a bad idea. There are people who depend on that behavior.

Comment: @meagar is right. Don't do this. See http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html

Answer (score 0):

This goes against all user accessibility documentation, so I don't really advise doing it, but if you really want to achieve this you can do so with JavaScript by removing the checkbox's `focus` when focussed by adding `onfocus="this.blur()"`:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onfocus="this.blur()" tabindex="-1" />
```

The reason I advise against this is because this now means the element is inaccessible when using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key on your keyboard. This is why I've also added `tabindex="-1"` to the checkbox in the above example, as without it the JavaScript event would reset the tab back to 1, making it impossible to access all interactive elements appearing after your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This code unfocuses after releasing the click, but still allows users to tab to the checkbox and use keyboard controls normally otherwise. Probably the best compromise you are going to get.

```js
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    this.blur();
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```